# Using the JSON results from a SharePoint API search response

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, json

I am using the SharePoint REST API to do a search. I am pulling back the JSON results and reading them as follows:

```
HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(querystring);

endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json; odata=verbose";
endpointRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
HttpWebResponse endpointResponse =(HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();

Stream webStream = endpointResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
var results = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
```

This works fine, I can see the results in JSON format. So I created a class from the JSON in VS 2017 and here is the classes created from the JSON (this was done automatically with File=>Paste Special=>Paste JSON As Classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class SharePointRESTResults
    {
        public class Rootobject
        {
            public D d { get; set; }
        }

        public class D
        {
            public Query query { get; set; }
        }

        public class Query
        {
            public __Metadata __metadata { get; set; }
            public int ElapsedTime { get; set; }
            public Primaryqueryresult PrimaryQueryResult { get; set; }
            public Properties1 Properties { get; set; }
            public Secondaryqueryresults SecondaryQueryResults { get; set; }
            public string SpellingSuggestion { get; set; }
            public Triggeredrules TriggeredRules { get; set; }
        }

        public class __Metadata
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
        }

        public class Primaryqueryresult
        {
            public __Metadata1 __metadata { get; set; }
            public Customresults CustomResults { get; set; }
            public string QueryId { get; set; }
            public string QueryRuleId { get; set; }
            public object RefinementResults { get; set; }
            public Relevantresults RelevantResults { get; set; }
            public object SpecialTermResults { get; set; }
        }

        public class __Metadata1
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
        }

        public class Customresults
        {
            public __Metadata2 __metadata { get; set; }
            public object[] results { get; set; }
        }

        public class __Metadata2
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
        }

        public class Relevantresults
        {
            public __Metadata3 __metadata { get; set; }
            public object GroupTemplateId { get; set; }
            public object ItemTemplateId { get; set; }
            public Properties Properties { get; set; }
            public object ResultTitle { get; set; }
            public object ResultTitleUrl { get; set; }
            public int RowCount { get; set; }
            public Table Table { get; set; }
            public int TotalRows { get; set; }
            public int TotalRowsIncludingDuplicates { get; set; }
        }

        public class __Metadata3
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
        }

        public class Properties
        {
            public Result[] results { get; set; }
        }

        public class Result
        {
            public __Metadata4 __metadata { get; set; }
            public string Key { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public string ValueType { get; set; }
        }

        public class __Metadata4
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
        }

        public class Table
        {
            public __Metadata5 __metadata { get; set; }
            public Rows Rows { get; set; }
        }

        public class __Metadata5
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
        }

        public class Rows
        {
            public Result1[] results { get; set; }
        }

        public class Result1
        {
            public __Metadata6 __metadata { get; set; }
            public Cells Cells { get; set; }
        }

        public class __Metadata6
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
        }

        public class Cells
        {
            public Result2[] results { get; set; }
        }

        public class Result2
        {
            public __Metadata7 __metadata { get; set; }
            public string Key { get; set; }
            public object Value { get; set; }
            public string ValueType { get; set; }
        }

        public class __Metadata7
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
        }

        public class Properties1
        {
            public Result3[] results { get; set; }
        }

        public class Result3
        {
            public __Metadata8 __metadata { get; set; }
            public string Key { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public string ValueType { get; set; }
        }

        public class __Metadata8
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
        }

        public class Secondaryqueryresults
        {
            public __Metadata9 __metadata { get; set; }
            public object[] results { get; set; }
        }

        public class __Metadata9
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
        }

        public class Triggeredrules
        {
            public __Metadata10 __metadata { get; set; }
            public object[] results { get; set; }
        }

        public class __Metadata10
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

So I now am trying to deserialize the results as follows:

```
 SharePointRESTResults resultX = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SharePointRESTResults>(results());
```

It appears to be serializing, but I am having problems pulling the class properties out.  I have tried:

```
var y = resultX.[d].[query].[Primaryqueryresult].[Relevantresults].[Table].[Rows].[results].[0].[Cells].[results].[0].[Key];
```

to try to get the results out but I get "The name 'd' does not exist in the current context" Has anyone tried to do this?  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an sample example to take a key value in your response.

```
let responseData:any[]=[];
let filteredArrayList = [];
responseData = result.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows;
console.log("responseData", responseData);

for (let i = 0; i < responseData.length; i++) {
     let PreferredName = [];
     let WorkEmail = [];

    //here iam geting two keys using key name.
    PreferredName = responseData[i].Cells.filter(response => response.Key === "PreferredName");

    WorkEmail = responseData[i].Cells.filter(response => response.Key === "WorkEmail");


    //here iam created sample object has been contain both value
    let object = { PreferredName: PreferredName[0].Value, WorkEmail: WorkEmail[0].Value }

     filteredArrayList.push(object);  
 }
//here you got All object value as key and value.
console.log("filteredArrayList value ",filteredArrayList);
```

Tested working fine.
if any error facing please let me know.

if solved your problem please upvote and mark as answer.

Thanks,
Muthukumar

Comment: It appears this is JavaScript.  I am programming in c#.  So although this answer does work for JavaScript, it is not c# specific.  That may be my fault for not indicating clearly in my code.  I ended up just deserializing to a Json object and using Linq to pull out the data I needed.  Thanks.

Comment: the rest of this looks good but I am getting errors from that first line: let responseData:any[]=[]; Thank you - Jake